# How to display laravel pagination numbers on top od the table

Tags: laravel, pagination

I am using Laravel pagination from controller to paginate some list of data in a table. The pagination numbers are only displaying on the bottom of the table. How do i get to display the numbers on the top of the table as well?
my view:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Make</th>
            <th>Model</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach ($cars as $car)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$car->make}}</td>
            <td>{{$car->model}}</td>
        </tr>
       @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>

<div class="pull-right">
    {{ $cars->links() }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you copy `{{ $cars->links() }}` at the top, it will also show you the same pagination like button. It looks like the following

```
<div class="pull-right">
    {{ $cars->links() }}
</div>
    <table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Make</th>
            <th>Model</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach ($cars as $car)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$car->make}}</td>
            <td>{{$car->model}}</td>
        </tr>
       @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>

<div class="pull-right">
    {{ $cars->links() }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$cars->links()` generates pagination button/links.
You can move it to wherever you like:

```
<div class="pull-right">
    {{ $cars->links() }}
</div>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Make</th>
            <th>Model</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach ($cars as $car)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$car->make}}</td>
            <td>{{$car->model}}</td>
        </tr>
       @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this on the top as well

```
<div class="pull-right">
    {{ $cars->links() }}
</div>
```